# Multidimensional array JS snippest

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

In below given JavaScript code I am unable achieve expected output. please help me to get resolve the given code.
Please check for the expected output.

In below given JavaScript code I am unable achieve expected output. please help me to get resolve the given code.
Please check for the expected output.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var record = []; 
        var idarr = ['5','2','-','3','-'];  
        var jobidarr = [];      
        var userid = 32;
        var newlogtimedata = ["2020/11/14 13:29:30","-","2020/10/10 13:33:49","-"];
        var newlogtimedataupdate = [];  
        var logcnt = 1;
        var j=0;
        
        for(var i = 0; i < newlogtimedata.length; i++){
                if(newlogtimedata[i] != "-"){
                    newlogtimedataupdate.push(newlogtimedata[i]);
            }
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i < idarr.length; i++){
            if(idarr[i] == "-"){
                logcnt++;
            }
            else{
                //for(var j = 0; j < idarr.length; j++){
                    record[[j]] = new Array();
                    record[[j]].push(parseInt(idarr[i]));
                    record[[++j]]= new Array();
                    /* record[[j]].push(JSON.stringify(parseInt(userid)));
                    record[[j]].push("-");
                    record[[++j]] = new Array();
                    record[[j]].push(newlogtimedataupdate[logcnt-1]);
                    record[[j]].push("-"); */
                    j++;
                //}
            }
          }
          console.log("record:::", record);
    });
```

```
/*
expected output will be
record:::
[ [5, 32, ['2020/11/14 13:29:30','-'],          
      [2, 32, ['2020/11/14 13:29:30','-'],
      [3, 32, ['2020/10/10 13:33:49','-'] ];  */
```

Comment: where is `'-'` of the date array coming from?

Comment: Considering it as hardcode value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this your desired result, not sure what it's supposed to represent though:

```js
var idarr = ['5', '2', '-', '3', '-'];
var userid = 32;
var newlogtimedata = [
  "2020/11/14 13:29:30", "-",
  "2020/10/10 13:33:49", "-"
];

const result = idarr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
  if (c === '-') return a;
  a.push([
    parseInt(c, 10),
    userid,
    [
      newlogtimedata[i] === '-' ? newlogtimedata[i - 1] : newlogtimedata[i],
       '-'
     ]
  ]);
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(var j = 0; j < idarr.length; j++){
    record.push([
        parseInt(idarr[i]),
        userid,
        [newlogtimedataupdate[logcnt - 1], '-']
    ]);
 }
```

To access data inside multi-dimensional arrays, it looks like this `myArray[2][1]`.

Example:
Here's a multi-dimensional array with some random values:

```
let myArray = [
    ['cake', 'cookie'],
    ['car', 'plane', 'train']
];
```

To access the elements inside `myArray`, you first select the index of one of the inner arrays. That means `myArray[0]` looks like: `['cake', 'cookie']`, and now you can select the elements inside the inner array like so: `myArray[0][1]` (which is `'cookie'`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use two indices for the arrays and pick an item as long as no sparator is coming.

```js
let idarr = ['5', '2', '-', '3', '-'],
    userid = 32,
    newlogtimedata = ["2020/11/14 13:29:30", "-", "2020/10/10 13:33:49", "-"],
    SEPARATOR = '-',
    record = [],
    i = 0,
    j = 0;

while (i < idarr.length && j < newlogtimedata.length) {
    record.push([idarr[i], userid, [newlogtimedata[j], '-']]);
    if (idarr[i + 1] === SEPARATOR && newlogtimedata[j + 1] === SEPARATOR) {
        i += 2;
        j += 2;
        continue;
    }
    if (idarr[i + 1] !== SEPARATOR) i++;
    if (newlogtimedata[j + 1] !== SEPARATOR) j++;
}

console.log(record);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```